# React: Render other blocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, I'm trying to communicate 2 component and render again one of them.

I have the following:

**layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
...
class Layout extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toolbar: 'none'
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    let me = this;
    return {
      changeToolbar: function (newToolbar) {
        me.setState({ toolbar: newToolbar })
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {Search, Nav} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="wrap">
        <Header Search={Search} />
        <Toolbar toolbar={this.state.toolbar} />
        <div className="main">
          <Nav />
          <div className="content">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Layout.childContextTypes = {
  changeToolbar: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default Layout;
```

**toolbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';
...
import ProductToolbar from '../components/toolbar/productToolbar';
import SalesToolbar from '../components/toolbar/salesToolbar';

class Toolbar extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    toolbar: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  state = {
    toolbar: this.props.toolbar
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(next_props) {
    this.setState({toolbar: next_props.toolbar})
  }

  render () {
    let bar = <div>{this.state.toolbar} undefined</div>;
    switch (this.state.toolbar) {
      case 'productToolbar':
        bar = ProductToolbar;
        break;
      case 'salesToolbar':
        bar = SalesToolbar;
        break;
    };

    return (
      <div className='toolbar show'>
        {bar}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Toolbar;
```

**productToolbar.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ProductToolbar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        productToolbar
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**productPage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
...

class ProductPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.changeToolbar('productToolbar');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Page</div>
    );
  }
};

ComisionPage.contextTypes = {
  changeToolbar: React.PropTypes.func
}

export default ProductPage;
```

when desire is loaded productPage.js create a special toolbar with options for Productpage.
I pass the name of the toolbar to render the new view, but it does not, missing or that I'm doing wrong?

another best solution was to pass directly toolbar

**productPage.js**

```
import ProductToolbar from '../components/toolbar/productToolbar';
...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.changeToolbar(ProductToolbar);
  };
```

It not works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure that you are rendering the element. Can you please change you switch statement to:

```
switch (this.state.toolbar) {
  case 'productToolbar':
    bar = <ProductToolbar />;
    break;
  case 'salesToolbar':
    bar = <SalesToolbar />;
    break;
};
```

---

Also, consider using a store (Redux, AltJs?) instead of context since they can get a bit complex on large apps (...I experienced the pain, until I switch to the 'store' approach)

Comment: Definitely support that second section: component to component communication should absolutely be discouraged, as it leads to a complicated and very difficult to debug chain of events. Using a unidirectional data flow with an action dispatcher (e.g., Redux) solves this problem eloquently.